# Getting the date format for the current locale

Tags: date, haskell, internationalization

When I first stumbled across the constant `defaultTimeLocale` in `System.Locale`, I supposed it should contain the default TimeLocale for the current locale.

After some trying around, I realized that it always contains the same constants and looking at the source code of `System.Locale` quickly revealed that it's in fact only a constant. (Later I realized that the type also tells me that. Since `defaultTimeLocale` isn't an `IO` value and doesn't take any arguments it *has* to be constant.)

What is the way in Haskell to get the current `TimeLocale` with respect to the current locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.CurrentLocale.currentLocale :: IO TimeLocale
```

from package [current-locale](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/current-locale)
looks suitable.

I did not test it. Looking at its source code, it should work. I actually do not like it very much since underneath it spawns *four* `date` subprocesses (!), which is rather overkill for this simple task, IMHO.

Probably it can be rewritten to use some C or POSIX function instead.

Comment: The problem with spawning date processes is even worse, since it seems to only work with the GNU date version. (it fails on mac)

Comment: @Kritzefitz It really needs to be rewritten, then. You can try to write the relevant C bindings (likely just one function), or see if some other package has a better locale handling -- I did not find anything, though.

Comment: Well I saw that C has `strftime` which has the format item `%D`, which formats the date according to the current locale. haskells `format` has the same format item, but it formats the date according to the given `TImeLocale`. I didn't find a C function to get the current format.

Comment: Also, its TimeLocale is not the one that Data.Time.Format will accept.